# plot the set $M:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}; Im \left( \frac{z+i}{z-2} \right) = 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

how to plot the set $M:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}; Im \left( \frac{z+i}{z-2} \right) = 0\}$ in the complex plane?
$Im(z)$ means the imaginary part of a complex number.

I have defined $z \in \mathbb{C}: z = x+iy, \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$\begin{align}
\frac{z+i}{z-2}=\frac{x+iy+i}{x+iy-2}&= \frac{[x+iy+i][x-2-iy]}{[x-2+iy][x-2-iy]}\\
&= \frac{x^2-2x-iyx+iyx-2iy-i^2y^2+ix-2i-i^2y}{x^2-2x-iyx-2x+4+2iy+iyx-2iy-i^2y^2} \\
&= \frac{x^2-2x-2iy+y^2+ix-2i+y}{x^2-4x+4+y^2}\\
&= \frac{x^2-2x+y^2+y-2iy+ix-2i}{x^2-4x+4+y^2} \\
\end{align}$

How should I go on ? And more important: How to draw that number?

Comment: ?? Well, what is the imaginary part of the fraction at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Im\frac{x^2-2x+y^2+y-2iy+ix-2i}{x^2-4x+4+y^2}=0\iff-2y+x-2=0$$

Comment: Why the downvote ?????